# iBooks library like effect

Tags: ios, ibooks

Can someone tell me how to achieve iBooks Library turning effect.(Not the pages).

Could that be achieved via Core Animation perhaps?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is what you search.

It's very little code and fully done in CoreAnimation.

https://github.com/devindoty/iBooks-Flip-Animation